# Canonical Cover example

Tags: database, functional-dependencies, canonicalization

I'm learning for my exams in the course databases and have some problems with the functional dependencies.

So I got the functional dependencies:

`A->BE, AE->BD, F->CD, CD->BEF, CF->B`

After decomposition and left-reduction I get:

`A->B, A->E, A->D, F->B, F->C, F->D, CD->B, CD->E, CD->F`

So after checking for transitivity's I get as solution:

`A-> BDE, F->CD, CD->BEF`

But I'm not sure if its right. I did the same steps like in this tutorial here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKYz5e7INTg

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found this page to calculate the canonical cover:

http://www.koffeinhaltig.com/

Important for the input is that between each attribute there must be a space.

So I found out that my solution is correct.

Here is my example:

http://www.koffeinhaltig.com/fds/ueberdeckung.php?fds=A+-%3E+B+E%2C+A+E+-%3E+B+D%2C+F+-%3E+C+D%2C+C+D+-%3E+B+E+F%2C+C+F+-%3E+B&language=de